# Can arrow functions incorporate the multiple arguments of a host function such as reduce?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I assume the answer to this question is no, but I'm not sure. Below is a reduce function , one is not using an arrow functions and one is. Is it possible to incorporate the second argument of the first into the arrow style ?

```
var s = arr.reduce(function(){

},0) // includes second argument
```

and........

```
var a = arr.reduce = () => {

} // ?
```

Comment: The first calls `arr.reduce` and the second overwrites `arr.reduce`...

Comment: In your second example, rather than invoke reduce, you're trying to reassign that identifier.

Comment: The second argument of `reduce` belongs to `reduce` not to the function passed as the first argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) can work with multiple params, they just need to be added inside parenthesis.

```
var s = arr.reduce((accum, currVal) => accum + currVal, 0);
                   ^              ^                       : Multiple arguments to the Arrow function
                                                       ^^^: Second argument of the `reduce` function
```

Here, the second parameter to the [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) can be passed normally. The arrow function(*first parameter*) has no effect on how the second argument is passed.

Answer (score 4):

The part of this code:

```
var s = arr.reduce(function(){

},0) // includes second argument
```

...that an arrow function would replace is purely this bit:

```
function() {
}
```

E.g.:

```
var s = arr.reduce(/*The function
goes
here*/,0) // includes second argument
```

The `0` is not related to the function being passed, it's a second argument to `reduce`.

So the equivalent of your first block is:

```
var s = arr.reduce(() => {

}, 0) // includes second argument
```

Although of course, if you're using `reduce`, in both code blocks you're going to want some arguments:

```
var s = arr.reduce(function(result, current) {
    return /*...something combining `result` with `current`...*/;
}, 0);
```

So:

```
var s = arr.reduce((result, current) => {
    return /*...something combining `result` with `current`...*/;
}, 0);
```

Or:

```
var s = arr.reduce((result, current) => /*...something combining `result` with `current`...*/, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to *call* the host function as usual, and can supply multiple arguments as usual. Just replace the function expression by the arrow function.

```
var s = arr.reduce(() => {
   …
}, 0);
```

Your second snippet did overwrite (assign to) `arr.reduce`, not invoke it.